# Calculate the average from 3 colors based on a percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-calculation

How can I calculate the average of three colors based on a given percentage?

For example we've **green**, **yellow** and **red** and want to get the average value:

The simplest way to do this is to create an image like this one:

[image]

And increase/decrease the `background-position`:

```
$('input').change(function(){
    $('#color').css({
        backgroundPosition: -this.value + "px 0"
    });
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/VY4D8/

...however I think that can be done *"better"* with `rgb/a` or `hex` as output.

Just for interpretation purposes:

- ** [0%] | `#ff0000`
- -- [1%]
- -- [2%]
- -- [3%]
- -- [4%]
- -- [5%]
- -- [...]
- ** [11%] | `#ffc600`
- -- [12%]
- -- [13%]
- -- [14%]
- -- [15%]
- -- [16%]
- ** [17%] | `#ffee00`
- ...etc...

Is there already an implementation for this problem or has one of you written something in the past?

**Update**

Got it, thanks to Eevee https://stackoverflow.com/a/15125778/1250044:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

$('input').change(function () {

    var max = this.getAttribute("max"),
        cur = this.value / max * max,
        r = Math.min(cur * 2, max),
        g = Math.min(max * 2 - cur * 2, max),
        rgb = g + "%, " + r + "%, 0%";

    div.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + rgb + ")";

}).change();
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/VY4D8/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do math?

You have:

- at 0%, red: `rgb(100%, 0%, 0%)`
- at 50%, yellow: `rgb(100%, 100%, 0%)`
- at 100%, green: `rgb(0%, 100%, 0%)`

If you want to figure out the color at 11%:

1. Figure out which section it belongs to.  11% of the full spectrum lies 22% of the way between red and yellow.
2. Interpolate: 22% of red plus 78% of yellow comes out to `rgb(100%, 78%, 0%)` or `#ffc600`.

Comment: Yeeh, nice thoughts, see my updated answer, and this fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/VY4D8/1/ any suggestions of improvement?

Answer (score -1):

You can do that CSS `linear-gradient`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/Jqdkq/

#### CSS:

```css
.gradient {
    background: linear-gradient(
        to right, 
        red, yellow, green
        );
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

#### HTML:

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

Comment: That's not really a big different to what I've already described my question: http://fiddle.jshell.net/VY4D8/ and btw a bit too complex to get this cross browser ready ;)